# World Problem Math Algebra Fraction

Tags: fractions

> The denominator of a fraction in simplest form is greater than the numerator by $3$. If $7$ is added to the numerator, and $5$ added to the denominator, then the fraction itself is increased by $\dfrac 1 2$. Find the original fraction.

I got the equation $\dfrac x {x+3}  = \dfrac {2x+14} {x+8}$.

When I solve this, I get a weird answer. My equation might be wrong. Can someone help me?

Comment: Why did you write "1   2"? Is it 12?

Comment: its 1/2 i just checked sorry

Answer (score 2):

Suppose the fraction (in simplest form) is $\frac{a}{b}$.

Then from the first statement $$b = a+3$$

From the second statement
$$\frac{a+7}{b+5} = \frac{1}{2}+\frac{a}{b}$$

You know have a simple system of equations which you can solve.

Comment: the 12 is supposed to be 1/2

Answer (score 1):

Let $x$ be the numerator. Then:

$\frac{x}{x+3}+\frac{1}{2}=\frac{x+7}{x+8}$

$\frac{1}{2}(x+8)(x+3)+x(x+8)=(x+3)(x+7)$

Then solve the quadratic equation.

Comment: This would be my interpretation, assuming the string "1   2" in the OP is actually just $12$

Comment: If it's not $12$ the OP is doing funkier maths than I ever did at that level.

Comment: Another interpretation is viewing the 2 statements as independent.

Comment: its supposed to be 1/2 or 0.5 @Daniel

Comment: I've edited my answer. Let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: @dan I got that, see my answer.

Comment: does x=2 @Daniel

Comment: Try it yourself. Put $x=2$ into the equation and see if $LHS=RHS$

Comment: And no, $x \neq 2$ for this case.

Comment: Shouldn't the 1/2 be added to the LHS not the RHS? This says the fraction decreased by 1/2 when you added 7 to the numerator and 5 to the denominator? Also, Daniel's answer doesn't give you two linear equations...

Comment: Right on all counts. I've edited it. Apologies I should rather go on here after waking up not right before going to sleep.